# How to read a text file with LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

I want to read a file to give a value. I have code where I choose between a constant value and a text file. The constant value works, but when I chose the text file, I manage to read only the first value at the path, and I get 0 at the next.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would like to help you, but I don't understand your question. I tried to clean up the grammar, but I do not know the relationship between the two images posted. Is one of those subVI nodes in the first image a call to the second image? Please make the label of your subVI nodes visible and then label your images so we can tell what code is called where.

Comment: Also, I removed the part about "NI-USB" from your question as that appears to be irrelevant -- you want to know something about reading the text file... how you use that value downstream is not relevant to the question. I didn't want people who might be able to answer you thinking this was a hardware-specific question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *I manage to read only the first value at the path, and I get 0 at the next*. Can you show us the contents of the text file, and the part of your LabVIEW code that actually reads it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a units problem. The "Get File Size" vi returns file size in bytes, but you have your "Read From Text File" configured to read a certain number of lines. Just wire a `-1` into the count input of the Read From Text File to get all the lines.